# using pipes with a find command

Tags: bash, awk, find

I have a series of delimited files, some of which have some bad data and can be recognized by doing a column count on them. I can find them with the following command:

```
find ./ -name 201201*gz -mtime 12
```

They are all gzipped and I do not want to un-archive them all. So to check the column counts I've been doing I'm running this as a second command on each file:

```
zcat ./path/to/file.data | awk '{print NF}' | head
```

I know I can run a command on each file through find with -exec, but how can I also get it to run through the pipes? A couple things I tried, neither of which I expected to work and neither of which did:

```
find ./ -name 201201*gz -mtime 12 -print -exec zcat {} \; | awk '{print NF}'| head
find ./ -name 201201*gz -mtime 12 -print -exec "zcat {} | awk '{print NF}'| head" \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a explicit loop aproach:

```
find . -name 201201*gz -mtime 12 | while read file; do
    echo "$file: "
    zcat "$file" | awk '{print NF}' | head
done
```

Answer (score 2):

More or less you pipe things through find like:

```
find . -name "foo" -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

So your command would look like:

```
find ./ -name "201201*gz" -mtime 12 -print0 | xargs -0 zcat | awk '{print NF}'| head
```

`-print0` and `xargs -0` just helps to make sure files with special characters dont break the pipe.

Comment: That seems to do the first file and is then giving me:

xargs: zcat: terminated by signal 13

Comment: Hm true, seems zcat assumes a closed pipe, Johannes' solution is correct. You need to zcat each file and pipe it to awk.